# Android: changing colour of floating label (hint) in TextInputLayout in error state

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I want the floating label of TextInputLayouts to change colour (e.g. to red) when there is an error. I can change the colour of the error text, but it has no effect on the appearance of the floating label (unlike someone in some other thread claimed). I couldn't use selectors for the hint colour to solve this problem either, as there does not seem to be a state defined for errors. Does anyone have any idea how to do this without having to manually program the change on error events/create a new java class (with EditText as parent)?

Here are the stylings I defined:

```
<style name="EditTextFloatingLabel" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textsize_caption_small</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextErrorText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/error_color</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextLayout">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/placeholder_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/input_field_background</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/default_margin_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/default_margin_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/default_margin_right</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextTheme">
    <item name="android:imeOptions">actionDone</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_line_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/nordea_blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/error_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/input_field_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textsize_caption</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/placeholder_color</item>

</style>

<style name="EditText">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/EditTextTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor_blue</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/default_padding_top</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/payment_text_input_padding</item>
</style>
```

Usage:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_field_error_wrapper_light"
            style="@style/EditTextLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/testlogin_text_input_end_padding"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/testlogin_text_input_start_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_padding_top"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/EditTextFloatingLabel"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/EditTextErrorText"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_field_light_error"
                style="@style/EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="#Input Field Disabled Light"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: try to my update answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I needed to perform some other actions as well when the layout was in error state, I decided to go with the solution of creating a custom error state and a custom TextInputLayout which can enter this state.

Code:

Defining the new error state in res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    ...

    <!-- custom states -->
    <declare-styleable name="ErrorState">
        <attr name="state_error" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

ErrorStateTextInputLayout class:

```
public class ErrorStateTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    private boolean hasError = false;
    private static final int[] ERROR_STATE = new int[]{R.attr.state_error};

    public ErrorStateTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ErrorStateTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ErrorStateTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        int[] state = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (hasError) {
            mergeDrawableStates(state, ERROR_STATE);
        }
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence error) {
        if (error == null) {
            setHasError(false);
        } else {
            setHasError(true);
        }
        super.setError(error);
    }


    public void setHasError(boolean error) {
        this.hasError = error;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }
}
```

Selector for setting the hint text colour:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:color="@color/disabled_text_color" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/error_color" app:state_error="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/input_text_color" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/placeholder_color" />
</selector>
```

This blog post helped me a lot: http://code.neenbedankt.com/example-of-custom-states-in-android-components/

Comment: how did you make it work? Calling setHasError(true) doesn't for me. I have set selector as textColor for error_appearance.

Comment: @NightFury I use a single color for the error text, so I am not sure about selectors (I think it should work with that too though). For me, simply defining a custom state attribute and setting its state at the appropriate places did the trick, as it can be seen in the code snippets above. Maybe if you post some code parts too, I can understand better where your problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..solid_red floating color.....

```
<style name="TextLabelInput" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/solid_red</item>
<item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/solid_red</item>
<item name="android:duration">200</item>
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/solid_red</item>

<!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
<item name="colorAccent">@color/solid_red</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/solid_red</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/solid_red</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/solid_red</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/solid_red</item>
```

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextLabelInput"

        >
```

hint text color manage over your main theme

which are colorPrimary and colorAccent

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The underline and the error message are red but the floating text is still accent colour.